# Can't push down bike pump

Tags: pump

I have Bell air glide 950 pump. I can't push down as the air is being blocked somewhere. I removed the tube/pipe that connects to the Schrader/Pestra valves. If I open the screw behind the pump, air comes out from there.

[image: Bell air glide 950]

Comment: What kind of valves are there on your tyres? In case those are Presta valves you'll have to unscrew the tiny nut at the top and give it a little push-down to loosen the stem.

Comment: Problem is not with the valve on the tire as I can't even push down the pump while it's not connected to any valve.

Comment: When I had that problem, I had to remove the tube from the base. The problem I had was that the flange through which air passes was getting blocked by a loose piece of plastic or such. That little bolt visible in your picture is what holds the tube to the base.

Comment: like you mentioned in the question, the tube is stuck or something. since you remove the tube theres air coming out?